# Unity networking: concurrent users

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity Pro offers 200 concurrent users in the network environment. Does this mean one host can handle 200 concurrent users or does it mean my project can handle 200 concurrent users? So, if I have game where players make their own "rooms": can 199 people join that room while 10.000 other players have also made rooms with 199 player in each. Or does it mean if one host has 16 players in his room other hosts can only have 184 players in their rooms all together?

Answer (score 3):

> Unity Pro offers 200 concurrent users in the network environment. Does
>   this mean one host can handle 200 concurrent users or does it mean my
>   project can handle 200 concurrent users?

**Answer:** Your project can handle 200 concurrent users.

**Prove:** My chat with Unity official *(Eduards - Digital Campaign Manager)*

[image]

For **further confirmation**, you can directly contact unity [**here**](http://download.unity3d.com/company/sales?type=sales). IMO! it is better to directly contact Unity (for further confirmation) if you want to purchase anything.

Answer (score 0):

it means how many users there can be at once, or so that is what i know, so there could be 16 people in a user made room where there are 184 in another. But this is for each server you make

Comment: Your response is confusing. I suppose by "room" OP already means "server". Could you please clarify whether you mean 200 per server or 200 altogether, globally?

Comment: @ThomasHilbert i mean 200 per server